# HTML Elements - Smart grid in angular showing same rows in all pagination

Tags: html, angular, grid, element

API calls getting triggered but the same record returns for each page click. We can't able to find the issue. Please help us.

We double checked the Payload and Results. All pages showing the same record as first page but last page shows different records.

Comment: Please add some pieces of code.